# Detect a event pattern in kafka event stream (e.g. window open - rain starts)

Tags: apache-kafka

i'm pretty new to kafka and I want to detect a certain "critical" series of events. I hope you can give me some help.

Example for my stream:

(1) Door opened
(2) Rain stops
(3) Door closed
(4) Window opened
(5) Window closed
(6) Window opend
(7) Door opened
(8) Rain starts

I want to detect the series of events (6) - (8) because its critical if the window is open and it starts raining.

Can you give me some advice how to implement such a detection? Do I need to write my own code in a kafka consumer or is this feature somehow natively available in Kafka? I don't want to detect the same critical sequence of events multiple times.

I have read about hopping or sliding windows, but i haven't understood if such a detection of a sequence of events is possible with that. The search didn't bring much up, although i'm pretty sure that this should be a pretty standard usecase...

Comment: Kafka only sees bytes. It doesn't parse your data, therefore doesn't have such a feature. Session windows is somewhat what you want, but those are associated with time, rather than explicit open/close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there only one door/window in your dataset? Or one location where rain is possible?

If not, my suggestion would first assign a unique id to each, only then will it be easier to track.

If you only want to track state of boolean events, build a KTable of open items with events such as

```
(door-456,true)
(rain,null)
(door-456, null)
(window-123,true)
(window-123,null)
(window-123,true)
```

At this point, your table would look only like this since all null values would delete the matching key from the table

```
(window-123,true)
```

As soon as you detect a new `(rain, true)` event, you'll need to query the table for any existing keys in the "open table" (at the location of the detected rain).

This is done with Processor Kafka Streams API and StateStores

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores